# Jquery .serialize isn't registering the values of the input-fileds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to serialize some data from a form.

The html:

```
<form class="span5 login navbar-form pull-right">
    <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
    <input class="last span2" type="password" placeholder="Lösenord" />
    <a class="loginbutton span1 btn btn-zen-inverse btn-mini" href="#">Logga in</a>
    <br />
    <a class="pull-right hidden" href="#">Glömt lösenord</a>
    <label class="pull-right hidden"><input type="checkbox" /> Kom ihåg mig</label>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loginbutton').click(login);
});

function login(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var params = $('form').serialize();
  console.log(params);
}
```

If i put some data in the html-fields and click the "a" tag with `.logintbutton` on it, the `console.log` is just empty, I expect it to push out the data. Whit serializeArray, I get an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide name in input. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2yPM/)

Modified HTML:

```
<form class="span5 login navbar-form pull-right">
    <input name='email' class="span2" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
    <input name='password' class="last span2" type="password" placeholder="Lösenord" />
    <a class="loginbutton span1 btn btn-zen-inverse btn-mini" href="#">Logga in</a>
    <br />
    <a class="pull-right hidden" href="#">Glömt lösenord</a>
    <label class="pull-right hidden"><input type="checkbox" /> Kom ihåg mig</label>
</form>​
```